# Compare and Swap : How to map the cas metadata field to document entity of my couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am using spring data to fetch documents from couchbase and i need to map the check and set metadata field **cas** to my document in order to implement the optimistic lock.

how can i do it without using n1ql query?

[CAS reference in Couchbase](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/concurrent-mutations-cluster.html)

Thanks

Comment: Technically, CAS stands for "compare and swap" in Couchbase (the documentation is sometimes contradictory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Java developer, but glancing at the [Spring.io docs for Spring Data Couchbase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/):

> If you want automatic optimistic locking support, all you need to do
>   is add a @Version annotation on a long field like this:
>
> Example 15. A Document with optimistic locking.
>
> ```
> @Document
> public class User {
>
>         @Version
>         private long version;
>
>         // constructor, getters, setters...
> }
> ```
>
> If you load a document through the template or repository, the version
>   field will be automatically populated with the current CAS value.